# Asp do not generate exception for oData query

Tags: asp.net, odata, asp.net-web-api, self-hosting

i'm developing a WebApi selfhost application with oData controllers.
 I have some base controller with method get

```
public class ODataControllerBaseClientFilter<T> : ODataControllerBase<T> where T : class, IClientId, new()
    {
        public ODataControllerBaseClientFilter(IDataService<T> service) : base(service)
        {
        }

        public override IQueryable<T> Get(string query = null)
        {
            var a = base.Get(query).ToArray();
            return base.Get(query);
        }
    }
```

There is an error in mapping EF entity to database, so if I execute query with code

```
var a = base.Get(query).ToArray();
```

EF will generate exception and return error to the client correctly.

But if I will remove this line and just return IQuerible object, there will **no any exception and no any result at client**! How can i resolve this problem?

UPD: text of the error

> {"Unable to determine composite primary key ordering for type
>   'Lk.Search.Data.Models.ReportClient'. Use the ColumnAttribute (see
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=386388) or the HasKey method
>   (see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=386387) to specify an
>   order for composite primary keys."}

UPD2: I use jquery ajax to get data from oData service (for testing I just use get request from browser)

Comment: `ToArray` actually attempts to execute the query, causing the error to surface.  The `IQueryable` has not yet been forced to attempt a query so there is not an error yet to report -- however an `IQueryable` isn't of any real value on the clientside.

Comment: That's right. But somewhere asp.net execute this query, serialize and return to client. But not in this case

Comment: Add the text of the error in your post.

Comment: it will throw error at the end of the query (when the serialization is called), and depending on how you call your webservice, there are several ways in client side to catch the error message (for example: in jquery ajax, you can get the error message in the fail fallback).